# Getting the "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key" when splitting out the date column by "/"

Tags: python, date, split

I tried to split the date column into 3 separate columns

```
df[['date1', 'date2', 'date3']] = df['Date'].str.split('/')
```

Here's the error I'm getting

```py
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

It works fine when I just type in df['Date'].str.split('/') and I was able to confirm that each list has only 3 elements.

I think it might have to do with some of the dates not having the full year, so the length of the column varies but I'm not sure why this would matter here.

```py
df['Date'].value_counts()

22/05/2022    10
26/12/05      10
26/12/08      10
11/05/14      10
12/05/2019    10
              ..
28/02/05       1
14/09/2015     1
27/09/2015     1
28/09/2015     1
17/08/2015     1

df['Date'].str.len().value_counts()

8.0     4850
10.0    2280
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) will return a Series (i.e. a *single* "column") with lists that contain the split elements).

```
df['Date'].str.split('/')

0    [22, 05, 2022]
1      [26, 12, 05]
2      [26, 12, 08]
3     [11, 5, 2014]
4     [12, 5, 2019]
5      [28, 02, 05]
6    [14, 09, 2015]
7    [27, 09, 2015]
8    [28, 09, 2015]
9    [17, 08, 2015]
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

So, the error you are getting is the result of trying to assign this single "column" to *three* new columns. To fix this, you need to set the `expand` parameter to `True`. This will expand the result into three different columns, which we can then assign as intended:

```
df[['date1', 'date2', 'date3']] = df['Date'].str.split('/', expand=True)

df

         Date  Count date1 date2 date3
0  22/05/2022     10    22    05  2022
1    26/12/05     10    26    12    05
2    26/12/08     10    26    12    08
3   11/5/2014     10    11     5  2014
4   12/5/2019     10    12     5  2019
5    28/02/05      1    28    02    05
6  14/09/2015      1    14    09  2015
7  27/09/2015      1    27    09  2015
8  28/09/2015      1    28    09  2015
9  17/08/2015      1    17    08  2015
```

**Data used**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': {0: '22/05/2022', 1: '26/12/05', 2: '26/12/08', 3: '11/5/2014', 
                 4: '12/5/2019', 5: '28/02/05', 6: '14/09/2015', 7: '27/09/2015', 
                 8: '28/09/2015', 9: '17/08/2015'}, 
        'Count': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

Incidentally, while the above should make the assignment work, if you are sure that the logic of the date strings is always: *day / month / year* (despite the differences in formatting), it is probably a better idea to rely on [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst` parameter set to `True`, and then to use [`Series.dt.day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) and same for `month` and `year`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year

df

        Date  Count  day  month  year
0 2022-05-22     10   22      5  2022
1 2005-12-26     10   26     12  2005
2 2008-12-26     10   26     12  2008
3 2014-05-11     10   11      5  2014
4 2019-05-12     10   12      5  2019
5 2005-02-28      1   28      2  2005
6 2015-09-14      1   14      9  2015
7 2015-09-27      1   27      9  2015
8 2015-09-28      1   28      9  2015
9 2015-08-17      1   17      8  2015
```

Note that you'll end up with proper and consistent `int` values this way.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by not having all dates in the 'Date' column haveing the same length.

The first format 22/05/2022 the length is 8 characters, but in the second format 26/12/05 the length is only 6 characters.

A solution would be to first convert all dates to a uniform length:

```
def convert_date(date):
    if len(date) == 8:
        date = "20" + date[-2:] + "/" + date[:2] + "/" + date[3:5]
return date

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(convert_date)
```

You can then split the dates into separate columns using:

```
df[['date1', 'date2', 'date3']] = df['Date'].str.split('/')
```